# Loads posts of different year via AJAX call

Tags: ajax, query

I need some advice with this one. I want to load posts of certain years depending what year the user clicks, to achieve this I have the following:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'year'  => '2015',
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="post-item" style="margin-bottom: 70px;">
            <div class="post-info">
                <p class="post-time">
                    <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                </p>
                <h2 class="post-title">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h2>
                <div class="post-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

with this I'm displaying all posts of 2015. My question is, how I could AJAXify this. I'm having different Buttons like a Menu with different years. And each querys a different year and displays it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To Ajaxify the request you need two parts, a php function, hooked to the wp_admin_ajax ( and the wp_admin_ajax_nopriv if you want it to be available for non logged in user) and a JavaScript to request the AJAX.

### PHP

```
add_action('wp_ajax_getpost_by_year','process_getpost_by_year');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getpost_by_year','process_getpost_by_year');

function process_getpost_by_year(){
    $year = $_REQUEST['year'];

    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'year'  => $year,
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    wp_send_json($the_query );
```

### JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your-wordpress-site.com/admin-ajax.php',
    data: {
        year: year
        action: 'getpost_by_year'
    },
})
.done(function(the_query) {
    // do stuff with the query result here
    console.log(the_query);
});
```

Don't forget to update `your-wordpress-site.com` to your site url, `year` variable, and